# Segmentation fault in C (beginner)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm a newbie in C programming and having pretty simple code here.
It compiles but won't run and a segmentation fault appears. I was looking for hours what could be wrong. Now I have a pretty good idea what segmentation fault means but not why it shows up in my small piece of code:

It's supposed to print out the user_id and group_id of the given parameter.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

     if(argc != 1){
         printf("ERROR");
     }

     struct passwd str;

     struct passwd *pointer = getpwnam(argv[1]);

     str = *pointer;

     printf("user: %d /ngroup: %d",str.pw_uid, str.pw_gid);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you want to access `argv[1]`, `argc` must be `> 1`, not `!= 1`. Also you should exit your program in the `if`.

Comment: if there is and error, shouldn't you try to stop the program from executing further?

Comment: Does `getpwnam` return a non-null pointer?

Comment: There are also a few other things that seems weird in your code, like the use of the `str` variable, which isn't needed. Or how you seem to be using `'/n'` to print a newline when it should be `'\n'`. And of course you not understanding `argc`.

Comment: ...and you do not explain the lifetime of 'pointer'.  Is the caller of 'getpwnam()' supposed to free 'pointer' when done?

Comment: You must allocate memory for pointer to structure in getpwnam. this method works for me                                                                     struct passwd str;


    struct passwd *pointer = (passwd*) malloc (sizeof (*pointer));

    pointer->a = 1;
    pointer->b = 2;

Answer (score 1):

You should check `pointer != NULL` before assign it into `str`.
getpwnam() return NULL in case no entry was found or an error occurred. See https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam for more detail.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can detect some problems here:

- Check if number of arguments is greater than 0, otherwise exit your program
- You should check if return value from `getpwnam`returns NON-NULL value.

I would rewrite this to:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     struct passwd str;
     struct passwd *pointer;

     //Number of arguments check
     if (argc <= 1) {
         printf("ERROR");
         exit(0);
     }

     pointer = getpwnam(argv[1]);
     if (pointer) {
         str = *pointer;
         printf("user: %d /ngroup: %d\r\n",str.pw_uid, str.pw_gid);
         printf("user: %d /ngroup: %d\r\n", pointer->pw_uid, pointer->pw_gid);
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

     if(argc < 2){
         printf("usage: %s username", argv[0]);
         return 1;
     }

     struct passwd *pointer = getpwnam(argv[1]);

     if (pointer == NULL) {
       printf("user: %s does not exist\n", argv[1]);
       return 1;
     }    

     printf("uid: %d\ngroup: %d\n", pointer->pw_uid, pointer->pw_gid);
     return 0;
}
```

You need to check if `getpwnam` returns `NULL`. If yes, that means that the user does not exist and dereferencing a NULL pointer results in undefined behaviour (usually a seg fault).

BTW: the variable `struct passwd str` is not needed, you can access `pointer` directly.